# Stanford parser output doesn't match demo output

Tags: parsing, neural-network, stanford-nlp

If I use the Stanford CoreNLP neural network dependency parser with the english_SD model, which performed pretty good according to the website ([link, bottom of the page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.shtml)), it provides completely different results compared to this [demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process), which I assume is based on the LexicalizedParser (or at least any other one).

If I put the sentence *I don't like the car* in the demo page, this is the result:

[image]

If I put the same sentence into the neural network parser, it results in this:

[image]

In the result of the neural network parser, everything just depends on like. I think it could be due to the different POS-Tags, but I used the CoreNLP Maxent Tagger with the english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger model, so pretty common I think. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, we use the `english-left3words-distsim.tagger` model for the tagger which is faster than the bidirectional model but occasionally produces worse results. As both, the constituency parser which is used on the demo page, and the neural network dependency parser which you used, heavily rely on POS tags it is not really surprising that the different POS sequences lead to different parses, especially when the main verb has a function word tag (`IN` = prepositon) instead of a content word tag (`VB` = verb, base form).

But also note that the demo outputs dependency parses in the new [Universal Dependencies](http://universaldependencies.org) representation, while the `english_SD` model parses sentences to the old Stanford Dependencies representation. For your example sentence, the correct parses are actually the same but you will see differences for other sentences, especially if they have prepositional phrases which are being treated differently in the new representation.

Comment: And do you know which pos Tagger and which model is used for the demo page? I find a lot of parses using the neural network parser where everything or at least very much depends on one word, that can't be correct...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is the `english-left3words-distsim.tagger` model. And if you are parsing short sentences, then this doesn't seem too unlikely that everything or almost everything depends on the main verb.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Actually the pos tagging of the second one makes more sense to me anyway. Thanks for your help and information!